# Moving NodeJS server using Express with Jade from Angular 1 to Angular 2

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, angular, pug

I have a working Node web server in Angular 1 with material design. Now some huge performance issues have hit me and I therefore want to move to Angular 2, which is supposed to have better performance. The Node server is currently set up to use Express with Jade as rendering engine and everything works as expected. My problem is that when configuring the web server for Angular 2, nothing is rendered saying `404 GET /index.html`. This is true, but I want to render `views/index.jade` as before, not a new `/index.html` file.

Here are the steps I have currently used to upgrade to Angular 2:

1. Adding all files and requirements from the [5 min quickstart guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html).
2. Run `npm install` (or similar) to install all the required dependencies.
3. Fiddled around in lots of files to try to render `/views/index.jade` instead of `/index.html`, but I just cannot find the proper place to configure this correctly.

I will list my file structure and the files I believe are important for this. Please let me know if any files need to be added.

**Folder structure (non-important files and folders removed):**

```
www
├── app <-- Added for Angular 2
│   ├── app.component.js
│   ├── app.component.js.map
│   ├── app.component.ts
│   ├── main.js
│   ├── main.js.map
│   ├── main.ts
│   └── reflect-metadata
├── app.js  <-- Angular 1 main file (now app/main.ts)
├── bin
│   └── www <-- Angular 1: start file run with 'node bin/www'
├── package.json
├── public
│   ├── javascripts
│   │   ├── angular-animate.js
│   │   ├── angular_controllers <-- Angular 1 client side controllers
│   │   │   ├── casesController.js
│   │   │   ├── dataController.js
│   │   │   └── // <snip other controllers>
│   │   ├── angular.js         <-- Angular 1 client side
│   │   ├── angular_js.js      <-- Angular 2 client side
│   │   ├── angular_js.js.map  <-- Angular 2 client side
│   └── stylesheets
│       ├── <snip, not important>
├── routes
│   ├── index.js
│   └── <snip other routes>
├── systemjs.config.js
├── tsconfig.json
├── typings
│   ├── <snip, auto-created>
├── typings.json
└── views
    ├── index.jade
    └── <snip, other jade files>
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "MyWebApp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/router": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "angular": "^1.5.6",
    "angular-animate": "^1.5.6",
    "angular-aria": "^1.4.8",
    "angular-bootstrap": "^0.12.2",
    "angular-material": "http://github.com/angular/bower-material/tarball/v1.0.9",
    "angular-sanitize": "^1.5.6",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.12",
    "body-parser": "~1.12.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.2",
    "bunyan": "^1.3.5",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.4",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "debug": "~2.1.1",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.1",
    "express": "^4.12.4",
    "forever-monitor": "^1.6.0",
    "graceful-fs": "^3.0.8",
    "jade": "~1.9.2",
    "jquery": "^2.1.4",
    "jquery-ui": "^1.10.5",
    "jsdom": "^5.4.1",
    "lodash": "^3.9.3",
    "moment": "^2.10.6",
    "morgan": "~1.5.1",
    "node-inspector": "^0.10.2",
    "node-sass": "^3.7.0",
    "node-sass-middleware": "^0.9.8",
    "nodemailer": "^2.3.0",
    "pg": "^4.3.0",
    "pg-promise": "^1.2.3",
    "phantomcss": "^0.10.4",
    "prettydiff": "^1.13.6",
    "promise": "^7.0.1",
    "pug": "^0.1.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "request": "^2.62.0",
    "resemblejs": "^1.3.1",
    "restify": "^3.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.0-beta.6",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.2.0",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "tether": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-jade": "^1.1.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings": "^1.0.4"
  }
}
```

**app/main.ts (mainly copied from app.js used for Angular 1):**

```
import { bootstrap }    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
bootstrap(AppComponent);

var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var sassMiddleware = require('node-sass-middleware');
var zone = require('zone');
var reflectmetadata = require('reflect-metadata');

var routes = require('../routes/index');
// <snip, vars for other routes>

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '..', 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// Add serving of static files from folder 'public'.
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'public')));

// Working for Angular 1 with Express/Jade    
app.use('/', routes);
// <snip, other routes)

// <snip error handlers and other stuff>

module.exports = app;
```

**app/app.components.ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',             <-- Is this important?
  template: '../views/index.jade' <-- I have tried multiple paths here.
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

**routes/index.js:**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index'); // Also tried '../viwes/index', but it made no difference.
});

module.exports = router;
```

tsconfig.json, systemjs.config.json, typings.json and similar files are as depicted on the [5 min quickstart guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html).

Running this setup using `npm start` (see package.json) now gives the message `Cannot GET /` in the browser. What can be wrong with my setup? Console output is as follows:

```
me@mycomp:~/www$ npm start

> MyWebApp@0.0.0 start /home/me/www
> tsc && concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite" 

[0] 
[0] > MyWebApp@0.0.0 tsc:w /home/me/www
[0] > tsc -w
[0] 
[1] 
[1] > MyWebApp@0.0.0 lite /home/me/www
[1] > lite-server
[1] 
[1] Did not detect a `bs-config.json` or `bs-config.js` override file. Using lite-server defaults...
[1] ** browser-sync config **
[1] { injectChanges: false,
[1]   files: [ './**/*.{html,htm,css,js}' ],
[1]   watchOptions: { ignored: 'node_modules' },
[1]   server: { baseDir: './', middleware: [ [Function], [Function] ] } }
[1] [BS] Access URLs:
[1]  -------------------------------------
[1]        Local: http://localhost:3003
[1]     External: http://192.168.1.1:3003
[1]  -------------------------------------
[1]           UI: http://localhost:3004
[1]  UI External: http://192.168.1.1:3004
[1]  -------------------------------------
[1] [BS] Serving files from: ./
[1] [BS] Watching files...
[1] 16.06.20 11:45:49 404 GET /index.html
[1] 16.06.20 11:45:49 404 GET /favicon.ico
[1] [BS] File changed: app/app.component.js
[1] [BS] File changed: app/main.js
[0] 11:45:49 AM - Compilation complete. Watching for file changes.
```

Comment: What is the content of `routes/index.js`? I guess you did not set a `/` path for it.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that one - I added it now. The only thing I do is to render `index` at `/`. This works for my Angular 1 app, but not for the current try for Angular 2.

Comment: That's impossible. Post the code please

Comment: The code is there, under the **routes/index.js:** header above. It just uses the `express.Router()` to render at `index`, nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

I know it. You should open `/` as opposed to `/index.html`.

Comment: Well, if you mean going to e.g. http://my.server.com instead of http://my.server.com/index.html in the browser that is exactly what I am doing. Or do you mean to configure this somewhere? If so, where can I configure that?

Comment: You are going to my.server.com. From this log `16.06.20 11:45:49 404 GET /index.html`, we can see that the browser is requesting my.server.com/index.html, which is apparantly not what you want. Check your browser. @Krøllebølle

Comment: It's not the browser for sure. Tested on Linux and Windows for the latest Chrome, Firefox and Edge (Win only).

Comment: It produces the same thing: `Cannot Get /`.

Comment: Is your project open sourced? I can't really reproduce it @Krøllebølle

Comment: Unfortunately not, it is an internal tool in my company so I can't make it available. Do you have a test setup that you have used? I tried [this demo](https://github.com/vladotesanovic/angular2-express-starter) for Angular 2 with Express and that works without any issues.

Comment: That should have nothing to do with ng2. Make sure you have routers set up correctly. @Krøllebølle

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there's a good chance that is a problem with lite-server. Have you configured that to use app/main.js when it boots up?

Also, it looks like there's no app.listen(PORT) in your app/main.ts file. Without that your express server won't respond to calls. Maybe you just left it out of what you posted here, I can't tell.

If neither of those are the culprit, try checking on the relative path that BrowserSync is serving files from. Maybe it's looking for files in a different place from where it's supposed to.